# js-ctypes: load a nsISupports from a Windows DLL

Tags: firefox, xpcom, jsctypes

Is it possible to use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) to call a Windows DLL and have it return a nsISupports instance?
The Windows DLL does XPCOMGlue, but by not needing NSModule I hope I can improve the registration process.
I was hoping there was a ctypes.nsISupports type defined to use as return value, so if it's possible, how do I declare the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading and experimentation, no, it doesn't look like you can. However, you could do the next best thing.

**1.** Create a win32 DLL exporting plain "C" symbols.

**2.** Create a "wrapper" XPCom component using JavaScript.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Implementing_XPCOM_components_in_JavaScript

**3.** Plumb each plain "C" function exported by the DLL into the JavaScript object.

Possible improvement: create a generic JavaScript shim that does the plumbing automatically.

Comment: I was trying to look into this, but haven't got my javascript component in order yet... As I agree this will create a working set-up, I'll accept your answer.